# How to filter with sql condtions in one query?

Tags: mysql

Hard to say how is my problem, but What I want to to is here:

```
  SELECT name
       , (SELECT count(age) as count) 
    FROM 'students' 
   WHERE class = '1c' 
       ;

  SELECT name
       , (SELECT count(age) as count) 
    FROM 'students' 
   WHERE class = '2b'
```

They are 2 separate mysql sentence, So how do I do that count in one sentence
to show something like:

```
+--------+-------+
| name   | count |
+--------+-------+
| Peeter |   5   |
| Harry  |   3   |
+--------+-------+
```

Comment: `... WHERE class IN ('1c','2b') ...` is more "expandable-friendly".

Comment: What do you want to count, ages or names?

Comment: Why my question is downvoted dramatically like this??? :)) I don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below - use `group by` and in `operator`

```
SELECT name,  count(age) as count
FROM 'students' 
WHERE class in ('1c','2b')
group by name
```